# checked property of Checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, html

So, I am dynamically generating `checkboxes` using pure `JS` based on content in a database. Each checkbox has to be in a separate line and can be checked or unchecked based on another value which is fetched from the database. For doing that, after I append a checkbox to the div, I am adding a tag to the div using the `innerHTML` property. But, now the checked property of the created `checkboxes` doesn't work. It is working if I remove the `innerHTML` part.

Can someone help? Here's my code:

```
var response = "Code1,Code2";

var arr = response.split(",");

var child = document.getElementById("divone");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, function(a){

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.name = 'FunctionCode';
    cb.value = a;
    cb.id = a;
    cb.checked = true;

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.htmlFor = a;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));

    child.appendChild(cb);
    child.appendChild(label);
    child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML + "<br />";
});
```

Comment: why are you using `Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr` ... when `arr` is clearly an actual Array?

Comment: `cb.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');` instead of `cb.checked=true` will work ... or ... `child.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))` instead of the innerHTML stuff

Comment: I tried child.appendChild(document.createElement('br')) but it didn't work. That's why I switched to this.

Comment: it does work, perhaps you did it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
cb.checked = true;
```

to

```
cb.setAttribute('checked',true)
```

demo:

```js
var response = "Code1,Code2";

var arr = response.split(",");

var child = document.getElementById("divone");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, function(a){

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.name = 'FunctionCode';
    cb.value = a;
    cb.id = a;
   // cb.checked = true;
    cb.setAttribute('checked',true)

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.htmlFor = a;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));

    child.appendChild(cb);
    child.appendChild(label);
    child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML + "<br />";
});
```

```html
<div id="divone"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to check the checkbox by default , use `defaultChecked = true;` instead :

```js
var response = "Code1,Code2";

var arr = response.split(",");

var child = document.getElementById("divone");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, function(a){

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cb.name = 'FunctionCode';
    cb.value = a;
    cb.id = a;
    // cb.checked = true;
    cb.defaultChecked = 'checked';
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.htmlFor = a;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));

    child.appendChild(cb);
    child.appendChild(label);
    child.innerHTML = child.innerHTML + "<br />";
});
```

```html
<div id="divone"></div>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be checked by default. Only if a particular condition is fulfilled, it should be checked.

Comment: you could've added the condition like `if(something) { cb.defaultChecked  ...` , and you didn't mention any condition in your question.